# Converting decimal to binary with user input

Tags: c#, converters, int32, console.readline

I wanna make a c# application that convert a decimal number into binary with the input from the user. I get a red squiggly line on bin, when declaring bin = Convert.ToString(decToBin,2);. I don't understand my problem, so any help would be appreciated.

```
int decToBin;
Console.WrinteLine("Enter a number that will be converted to binary")
decToBin = Int32.Parse(Console.Readline());

bin = Convert.ToString(decToBin,2);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: And you probably need to print it too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you haven't declared bin. it should be

```
int decToBin;
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number that will be converted to binary");
decToBin = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string bin = Convert.ToString(decToBin, 2);
Console.WriteLine(bin);
```

Comment: yeah you are right. Thank you for that, but I get another problem. When running this code, the outcome is stil a decimal number instead binary. What do I do wrong? Is my code correct for converting decimal into binary?

Comment: @user3387813 you are getting decimal because you did not convert it into binary! This snippet simply accepts a number in "decToBin", converts it into string using "Convert.ToString()". But you are not converting it anywhere!

Comment: @Bodhi so ur saying that this line of code shoud be different? 
string bin = Convert.ToString(decToBin,2);

Comment: @TNJ I am very sorry, i did not see that second parameter in Convert.ToString(). Can you tell me the inputs?

Comment: @TNJ what do you get in bin. isn't it 101?

Comment: @Bodhi Basicly I used this code as a converter: string binary = Convert.ToString(31, 2); the outcome will be 11111. I wanna make it dynamic instead hardcoded it. Thats why the first parameter is dynamic, the second is the base 2. Cauze binary is in base 2.

Comment: @Ehsan what do you mean 101? If I run this app and my input is 13(example), the outcome will be 1101.

Comment: @TNJ Yes, this is what i get if i enter 13. 1101.

Comment: @Ehsan I mean my outcome _italic_ should be 1101. But this code isn't working. I have changed it, but stil it doens't show what I would expected: 'code' string decToBin; 'code' Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to be converted into binary"); 'code' decToBin = Console.ReadLine(); 'code' decToBin = Convert.ToString(decToBin,2) 'code' Console.WrinteLine(decToBin);

Comment: @TNJ you need to write this line at the end.  Console.WriteLine(bin);

Comment: @Ehsan ahh YEss finaly it works. Thank you verry much;-)

Comment: @Ehsan how do i suppose to do that, I'm a noob here. That was my first post of asking a question

Comment: @TNJ see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

This works well and waits for key after print. you were also missing a comma and some large letters.

```
   Console.WriteLine("Enter a number that will be converted to binary");
   var decToBin = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

   Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(decToBin,2));

   Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to what Ehsan mentioned,

Console.Readline() should be Console.ReadLine();
**L caps**

Answer (score 0):

> when declaring bin = Convert.ToString(decToBin,2);.

This is not how you **declare** variables in C#. The syntax is

```
<Type> <VariableName> [ = <Value>];
```

e.g.

```
string bin = Convert.ToString(decToBin, 2);
```

or

```
var bin = Convert.ToString(decToBin, 2);
```

Also see the C# language specification, §8.5.1:

> The local-variable-type of a local-variable-declaration either
>   directly specifies the type of the variables introduced by the
>   declaration, or indicates with the identifier var that the type should
>   be inferred based on an initializer.